# How to use Twitter Bootstrap in productions, LESS or compressed CSS?

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I'm working in J2EE project which want to use Twitter Bootstrap as main style for front-end, with some customizations for fitting product.

I don't know should I use LESS or CSS format introduced by Twitter Bootstrap, if use LESS I have to compile these files to CSS at server or client side, which Java framework help me at server side because I need to cache the stylesheet in product mode, otherwise don't need to cache them.

I'm wondering that precompile at client site will impacts to product performance, anyone made a benchmark for that?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [wro4j](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/) for that, which can be used as a runtime or build-time solution for server-side transformation of less into css and also handles the caching. You can read more about less support for wro4j here:

- [Wro4j, Page Load Optimization and Less.js](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/wro4j_page_load_optimization_and_lessjs.html)
- [Less css support](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/LessCssSupport)

Comment: wro4j is certainly an interesting tool, but the question was mainly about benchmarking client-side less.js. Do you have any results for that?

Comment: Though I have no benchmark result available (maybe I'll do some later), it should be pretty straight forward that compiling less into css on each request has an impact on performance when comparing to serve of precompiled & cached content.

Answer (score 0):

I would say go with CSS if you don't want the hassle of dealing with server-side compilers.

If you do go that route this is a good less compiler for java:
http://www.asual.com/lesscss/

Never compile client-side unless that is all you have to work with, it takes a huge impact on the browser vs gzipped or compressed/minified css.

:)

Comment: If use compressed CSS, we cannot use LESS mechanism to customize the stylesheet defined by TB.
Do you know any project use http://www.asual.com/lesscss/ as server side pre-compile?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but it does have a command line option as documented by a third-party user here: http://www.dopefly.com/techblog/entry.cfm?entry=358

Comment: Can you quantify the *"huge impact"*? "huge" as in orders of magnitude, or are there any half-smart client-side caches?

Comment: Caching doesn't always happen with compilations and generally the sources is re-compiled each time. There are ways to mitigate this however I have not looked directly at the source of lessjs to see if they have taken these measures such as utilizing local storage as a cache layer, either way, flickers, latency, etc. Orders of magnitude? Anywhere from near-second to a few seconds or more at most.

Answer (score 0):

LESS is awesome for development, but only use the compiled .css for production. Whatever you do, absolutely do not have less.js/LESS compile client-side for production. Even if you you experience snappy response times with less.js and .less files in the head of your HTML during development, the response times for everyone else will be all over the board. I don't know if anyone can make good benchmarks for it, because of the endless number of ways you could import/add the LESS files. If you Have 130 mixins in separate .less files imported and compiled client-side that's going to have difference performance than one .less file, even if the resulting size is the same. And then taking file size, computer hardware specs etc. into consideration, it would be tough to get reliable results with any benchmarks.

My recommendation is to either use use something like node.js and less.js to compile to css on the fly every time you save. Or use one of the handful of nice gui tools out there that will watch the project and compile every time you save. (LESS.app, Crunch App, WinLESS etc)

Comment: I have to add that I misread the last sentence, which might be material to the OP. I thought the question was pertaining to "compiling client side" not pre-compiling.

Comment: Yes, I meant client side compiling. However, how to customize the twitter bootstrap to fit our product after download bootstrap.css, should I use css overriding instead of LESS mechanism?

Comment: It depends on how much you care about easily merging in future enhancements, how much customizing you will do, etc. In general though, if you are comfortable using LESS then I would continue to edit the native LESS files, and have the CSS re-compile automatically every time you save.

Comment: Also, it depends on 1) if you care about easily merging in future enhancements. 2) how much customizing you'll do, 3) are you just overriding styles or adding other classes etc. If you are adding your own styles (versus just overriding existing styles), I recommend that you create your own LESS "components" as extensions to Bootstrap's native components and just add the @import links for the new files to bootstrap.less